# Minecraft skin bug?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So I have a Samsung phone and I play minecraft bedrock edition. Whenever I try to open another tab it disconnects my friends from my world. This also happens when I try and change my skin. Does anyone know if I can change it and why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

If you stay inactive from your LAN world, everyone gets disconnected. This goes for any tab outside of Minecraft.

What you can do is to use split-screen, but it doesn't look good, so get to a tab, and when you think it's nearly time that your friends get disconnected, go back.